# Regex not returning 2 groups

Tags: regex

I'm having a bit of trouble with my regex and was wondering if anyone could please shed some light on what to do.

Basically, I have this Regex:

```
\[(link='\d+') (type='\w+')](.*|)\[/link]
```

For example, when I pass it the string:

```
[link='8' type='gig']Blur[/link] are playing [link='19' type='venue']Hyde Park[/link]"
```

It only returns a single match from the opening `[link]` tag to the last `[/link]` tag.

I'm just wondering if anyone could please help me with what to put in my `(.*|)` section to only select one `[link][/link]` section at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the wildcard selection ungreedy with the "?" operator. I make it:

```
/\[(link='\d+')\s+(type='\w+')\](.*?)\[\/link\]/
```

*of course this all falls down for any kind of nesting, in which case the language is no longer regular and regexs aren't suitable - find a parser*

Comment: I had to change some other aspects of the regex for it to make sense to my ecmascript brain...

Comment: @annakata: I think this question would have been a reasonable candidate for the "regexhtmlparserquestions" tag you once put up. ;-)

Comment: There is still one question that has it. You can still go for the Taxonomist badge. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions Info a is a fantastic site. [This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) gives an example of dealing with html tags. There's also an [Eclipse plugin](http://regex-util.sourceforge.net/) that lets you develop expressions and see the matching in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the .* in the middle of your regex non-greedy.  Look up the syntax and/or flag for non-greedy mode in your flavor of regular expressions.